# out of memory during GC, will try disk-based GC

Tags: specman

I have a long simulation that I need to improve its performance.
I see in the log files messages like: "Out of memory during GC, will try disk-based GC" that takes a lot of simulation time. what is Specman doing at that time, and how can I eliminate it in order to improve run time?

Answer (score 1):

As Mentioned above, Specman is doing disk-based GC since you ran out of memory during a regular GC (which consumes memory in that process). Writing to disk is slow and this is why your simulation is slow.
Use config mem -disable_disk_based_gc. This will activate on-the-fly GC, which is a lot faster that disk-based, and consumes less memory in the process that the regular GC.

Answer (score 0):

Specman is doing garbage collection (gc) to free memory of objects that are no longer in use. Generally, this is good, since otherwise you would have to do it yourself, like in C/C++. 
You can control GC threshold and increments using config memory command. Use lower value for the threshold to prevent getting out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You get these messages since specman is trying to do garbage collection and it runs out of memory during the process, so it switches to sisal based gc.
In order to improve the performance, you can increase the optimal_process_size to give specman more memory for the gc, or disable the disk based gc.
In the latter case specman will use on the fly gc which is faster

Answer (score 0):

You lack Ram for your simulation.
Specman tries to use disk drive to access more memory.
Disk access is slow.
You can use the on the fly GC to get better performance in addition to configuring better values for gc_threshold  and optimal_process_sise.

Answer (score 0):

Specman is doing garbage collection using disc space. It is slower but uses less cpu. In the configuration there is an option to cancel the disc garbage collection.